# How to replace Sphinx cover page when making a PDF

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, pdflatex

I need to change the cover page of a Sphinx-generated latexpdf from RST.

How can I do that without modifying the Sphinx package itself?

I've noticed latex_preamble in the conf file but that only seems to append things. If that is the way an example would be helpful. Right now whatever I do only seems to add to rather than remove the cover page.

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer and posting it here for anyone else who is interested.

In the **conf.py** file add the following entry:

```
"maketitle": "\\input{your_cover.tex}"
```

where **your_cover.tex** is your LaTeX file you want to be the cover.